# Insert text at cursor position

Tags: c#, vba

I need to insert text from a variable at the cursor position no matter in which window/program it is located, so whenever the C# or VBA (preferably C#) code will run it will just write that text from the variable.

**PD:** im using VoiceBot to create custom scripts, C# default script looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

public static class VoiceBotScript
{
public static void Run(IntPtr windowHandle)
{
    var myText = "This is a simple text";
    //how to add this text variable to cursor position? 
}
}
```

**To clarify:** VoiceBot can run C# or Visual Basic scripts on voice commands, after writing the script it will be triggered by voice. https://www.voicebot.net/ I need to run this script for example when playing a game and chat is selected, to warn player about X.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to simulate the keyboard and send keystrokes to the currently active application. For example:

```
SendKeys.Send("+This is a simple text");
```

Note that as you are simulating the keyboard, you need to explicitly invoke the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (with the `+` character, as in the example) to get an uppercase character. There are some other caveats including other characters you have to escape, so do not simply feed this method a user-provided string without processing it first. For more information, see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: hmm tried System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("+This is a simple text"); and doesnt seem to do anything.

Comment: Hmm, have you made sure the target application is active (in the foreground) when the method is called?

Comment: sure, i tried it with notepad++ in a blank document on first line

Comment: Not sure what to say. I just tried it and it worked. You do have to make sure the application is running a message pump and able to send messages. It could be an interactivity issue with VBA.

Comment: in which aplication you tried it, does it work in chrome for example?

Comment: I tried it in Notepad. Put a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` call first which gave me the chance to run the program then alt-tab to Notepad.